# How to open an ios Application on Tap of Push Notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification

May i know, how to open an ios application, on tapping on notification.
Or when we swipe an icon (in case when iphone is locked.) of notification?

Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 12):

The OS handles the behavior when tapping the notification as it comes in.  Doesn't matter if it is sent by a 3rd party or not, if it is going through APNS, it will open the application and inside `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
         // Launched from push notification
         NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    }
}
```

If the app happens to be already open when the notification comes in the OS will fire the delegate method:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {   
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: Actually no, that method is only called if the app is already running, otherwise you get the push payload in application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Very true.  Good catch, I posted without thinking :)  The [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] is the dictionary that you can peruse when launched from an app NOT running state.

Comment: Hi Filip, Thanks for the clarification, so irrespective of whether app is open or not, tap or swipe on push notification does open the associated Application. Right?. Its just that, it calls different methods depending on state of App (OPEN/CLOSED/BACKGROUND).

Comment: Correct.  If the app is open when the notification comes in, the delegate method in my answer above gets called.  If the app is not open when the notification comes in, the app is launched (by the OS) and inside applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions, the launchOptions dictionary will have the info associated with the notification.

Answer (score 6):

It's automatically open the app. Apple do the stuff for us. We don't need to code anything for open the app.

Comment: How can we open a particular view controller on tapping a push notification ?

Comment: @Rinku: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` Will be called when user tap on the push notification and opens the app, there you can set your ViewContrller as rootView or just present it from there.

Answer (score 1):

On pressing the local notification, app launches automatically.

Comment: Great, but that's a local notif, not a push notif. Quite a difference there :)

Comment: Is it?. Even if i am implementing and integrating third party push notification into my application. Will it open on any of the action may it be tap on notification or sliding icon in case if phone is locked?

Answer (score 1):

The app is opened automatically, but the last view controller you were in. So in order to open you desired view controller just implement application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
Further explanation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a).